# Android SQLite: what is the best way to create a copy of database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

What is the best way to create a copy of all data from database A in database B using SQL (and not a file copy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two approach check which one you prefers. but I think if possible i will follow first approach. But I have never done it.

**First Approach** Copy the first database and paste with some othername see following url

[How to copy existing database from one app to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662181/how-to-copy-existing-database-from-one-app-to-another)

**Second Approach** copy the contents of two database

**Step-1** First Attach two databases

```
ATTACH DATABASE filename AS database-name;
```

The DATABASE keyword is optional, but I like the clarity of it. filename should be the path to the database file you wish to attach, and the database-name is a unique name.

**Step-2** Run Insert Into commands for the tables you want to transfer.

```
INSERT INTO X.TABLE(Id, Value) SELECT * FROM Y.TABLE;
```

Comment: The first approach suggest file copy which is not what I am looking for. As for the second one - can you please give a bit more detailed example (code snippet perhaps)? Thanks